# GIMP brush size can't be size 2 or size 4

Tags: gimp

This is driving me crazy...

I can select a brush size of 1 pixel, and it's fine.
I can select a brush size of 3 or 5 pixels, also fine.

But when I set the size to 2 or to 4 pixels, GIMP will use a brush size of 3 instead???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends which brush you use. The `1. Pixel` wants to be 3 pixels, but the `Pixel (1x1 square)` works for 2px:

[image]

Theses two brushes are "parametric" brushes (their outline is defined a bit like a path). You can also define a  bitmap brush:

- Create a 2x2 image
- Fill with black
- Either:

  - Export as .GBR in one of your brushes directories, and select it in the brush list
  - Copy to clipboard, and use the `Clipboard mask` brush (the `Clipboard mask` brush assumes the Foreground  color, the  `Clipboard image` brush keeps the color it was created with)

Comment: Thank you. Somehow, it is a lot harder to draw with that brush thuogh. E.g. holding SHIFT for straight lines often still makes lines that are not fully straight. It also often misses pixels.

Comment: Yes, because its center is not centered on a pixel but between pixels. You can use a non-parametric brush, see augmented answer.